# Tooltip não é setado dentro do modal

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

Já li e testei várias perguntas daqui do stackoverflow pt e en e mais alguns issues no github porém nenhuma me ajudou a resolver o problema.

Estou tentando setar um tooltip dentro do modal, porém ele só mostra o `title` e o tooltip não é setado. Como na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu já testei setar o tooltip quando o modal é exibido. Dessa maneira:

```
$(ele).on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

Não funcionou.

O `html` do `button` está dessa maneira:

`<button class="btn btn-primary btn-select2" data-toggle="tooltip" type="button" data-placement="top" title="Selecionar todos"><i class="fas fa-check-double"></i></button>`

Até então, nem o `title` aparecia.

Toda vez que o modal é aberto, faço um foreach pra encontrar esses botão (para outra função) porém eu aproveitei e setei novamente o `title`, o `data-original-title` e o `tooltip`, desta forma:

```
$('modal').find('.btn-select2').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('title', 'Selecionar Todos');
    $(this).attr('data-original-title', 'Selecionar Todos');
    $(this).data('placement', 'top');
    $(this).tooltip();
});
```

Foi ai que começou a aparecer o `title` igual na imagem, porém sem sucesso quanto ao `tooltip`. Alguma maneira de isso ser resolvido?

Comment: Recentemente tive um problema parecido porque em alguns lugares precisava de 2 atrutos `data-toggle`, para resolver coloquei os atributos no HTML como `data-tooltip="tooltip"` e no JS `$('[data-tooltip="tooltip"]').tooltip()`. Veja se isso resolve.

Comment: Testei dessa maneira, também sem sucesso.

Comment: Veja se o código da resposta te ajuda.

Comment: Cara que tipo de componente é esse ai que vc está usando?? Ele não parece nada que seja padrão do Bootstrap3... confere na documentação desse cara se ele aceita esse tipo de customização com tooltipe

Comment: É um template que utiliza o bootstrap, em relação ao template, ele utiliza tudo da mesma forma que o boostrap

Answer (score 3):

Estou postando somente para que veja que está funcionando para ver se fez algo diferente.

O *tooltip* aparece quando coloca o mouse no botão check dentro do modal.

```js
$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});

$('modal').find('.btn-select2').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('title', 'Selecionar Todos');
    $(this).attr('data-original-title', 'Selecionar Todos');
    $(this).data('placement', 'top');
    $(this).tooltip();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-select2" data-toggle="tooltip" type="button" data-placement="top" title="Selecionar todos"><i class="fas fa-check-double"></i>Check</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```